# Sharepoint custom List

Tags: sharepoint

I am using Sharepoint Designer 2007 and doing the Custom Validations(through Aspx controls).

The validations are working perfectly. But the issue is when there is a validation failure, I have Corrected the failed fields and leave the other fields as it is.

In this case I am not getting any values from unchanged fileds in my form into the list.

This is like Viewstate problem.

Could anyone help this!!

Hari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds more like a control refresh problem.  I looks like the browser is not refreshing the controls.  The controls are actually empty behind the scenes, but because the browser didn't refresh the controls you don't see it on the UI side.  It could be related to ViewState/Session State as you suspect.

To enable Session State in SharePoint, start here:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markarend/archive/2010/05/27/using-session-state-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: Thanks Cornelius. I have made enableviewstate property to false for the aspx controls and that worked. Many thanks for all the viewers..